# Kotlin stub/placeholder function for unimplemented code

Tags: kotlin

Scala's Predef has a bunch of shorthand functions including one for unimplemented code, namely ???. Does Kotlin have anything similar rather than having to resort to the longhand

```
throw Error("Code not yet implemented")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Kotlin 1.0, you can use the [`TODO` function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-t-o-d-o.html) from the Kotlin standard library, which takes an optional message.

Comment: To clarify, the question was not about syntax but rather about whether such a pre-existing function existed in Kotlin. As demonstrated in this answer, it is trivial to write such function one's self. Scala library writers must have thought, though, that the use case was frequent enough to include it in their standard library.

Comment: I see. I thought you specifically asked about syntax, because `???` looks to me as a special syntax, rather than a library function :) But no, currently the closest analogue to what you're asking is the `error` function I mentioned. Please leave a request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT if you think an alternative without the error message would be helpful.

Comment: Yes `???` is a function. You bring up a good point, though, about how it looks like special syntax because Scala allows other non-usual characters in identifiers. If the function in Predef was called `todo` rather than `???` that would arguably be clearer.I noticed in kotlin.test package there is a function called `todo` (which takes a function argument) and serves a slightly different purpose.

Comment: Serendipitously, Alexander's answer is the quintessence of why allowing special characters in programming language identifiers is a questionable design decision! :)

Comment: Link to the TODO function docs: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-t-o-d-o.html

Comment: I think this answer should be updated. I think the link to the Kotlin TODO function is enough.